# How to apply angular filter on a Angular-Kendo Dropdown list?

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, angular-filters, kendo-dropdown

Below is my data source which needs to be binded to two kendo drop down list. One is for Program and another for IForm. I need the filteration to be done in the dropdown itself.

```
$scope.programIFormList = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        data: [
                    {
                        Name: "Program1",
                        IsProgram: "true",
                        ProgramId: 1,
                        Status: 0,
                        PatientId: 1,
                        StartDate:"",
                        EndDate:""
                    },
                    {
                        Name: "Program2",
                        IsProgram: "false",
                        ProgramId: 2,
                        Status: 0,
                        PatientId: 1,
                        StartDate:"",
                        EndDate:""
                    }
                ]
    });
```

Below is html code:

```
 <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                    <select id="patient" kendo-drop-down-list k-data-text-field="'Name'" k-data-value-field="'PatientId'"  k-data-source="patientList" >                      
                    </select>
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                    <select kendo-drop-down-list k-data-text-field="'Name'" k-data-value-field="'ProgramId'" k-data-source="programIFormList | filter:{IsProgram: true}" k-cascade-from="'patient'">
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                    <select kendo-drop-down-list k-data-text-field="'Name'" k-data-value-field="'ProgramId'" k-data-source="programIFormList | filter:{IsProgram: false}"  k-cascade-from="'patient'">
                    </select>
                </div>
```

Here, I am trying to apply angular filter. But it's not working. How can this be achieved using Kendo Angular?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this approach

```
angular.module("MyApp", [ "kendo.directives" ])
      .controller("FilterController", function($scope){


          $scope.programIFormList = new kendo.data.DataSource({
              data: [
                          {
                              Name: "Program3",
                              IsProgram: "true",
                              ProgramId: 1,
                              Status: 0,
                              PatientId: 1,
                              StartDate: "",
                              EndDate: ""
                          },
                          {
                              Name: "Program1",
                              IsProgram: "false",
                              ProgramId: 2,
                              Status: 0,
                              PatientId: 1,
                              StartDate: "",
                              EndDate: ""
                          }
              ],
              filter: [
                { field: "IsProgram", operator: "eq", value: "true" }

              ]
          });
      });
```

Comment: The approach is correct if there is only a single Dropdown. But i have two dropdowns and i need to bind this single datasource to both and doing the filtering at View Level. Is there anyway to pass the filter value from HTML view? Is there any directive created by Kendo UI?

Comment: We can use such type of inline filter but I am not sure about this. I tested it with your example but its not working but may be if you can explore more then may be can help.                            **k-filter="' { field: 'IsProgram', operator: 'eq' ,value:'true' }'"**